# Accessing a url from a button click in android studio

Tags: java, android, url, button, android-intent

So I have been trying to access a simple webpage from a button click in my app on android studio. Every method that I have tried has crashed the app when I have tried to run it. Basically I just want to click the button and then have a webpage pop up such as google. Right now I have a currently broken method that I made and am trying to use within the button click but it does not work. Any help would be appreciated.

```
public void openWebURL( String inURL ) {
    Intent browse = new Intent( Intent.ACTION_VIEW , Uri.parse( inURL ) );

    startActivity( browse );
}

public void buyButtonOnClick(View view){
    openWebURL("www.google.com");
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "broken method"?

Comment: Post the stacktrace

Comment: Try to put https:// in the url. If it still crashes post the stacktrace.

Comment: @DanielSpiess that worked, thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

You will need to launch **ACTION_VIEW** intent with a correctly formatted url.

```
public void showExternalBrowser(Activity activity, Uri uri) {
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    i.setData(uri);
    activity.startActivity(i);
}

showExternalBrowser(activity, Uri.parse("https://www.google.com"));
```

Note the **scheme** (https) and **host** (www.google.com) combined make a valid url.